# gtk.css:2:33: Failed to import in Grass GIS

Tags: grass-gis, linux, image-classification

When first I run GRASS GIS 7.6.0, there is an error message :

```
(gis_set.py:4772): Gtk-WARNING **: 16:05:43.648: Theme parsing error: 
gtk.css:2:33: Failed to import: Error opening file 
/home/mega/.config/gtk-3.0/whisker-tweak.css: No such file or directory
```

I ignore the message. I start GRASS GIS. I import raster and vector. I add raster as RGB.

Image is displayed in map display window. Then I choose Imagery > classify image > Interactive input for supervised classification. Then GRASS GIS supervised classification tool appear. 
But, no image in training area display and preview display. Then I import training area from vector map.

Suddenly, all window GRASS GIS quit except GRASS GIS terminal window.

So, how to solve this problem? I run in MX Linux 19.

Comment: Could you update to GRASS GIS 7.8? It comes with 730 improvements compared to GRASS GIS 7.6: https://trac.osgeo.org/grass/wiki/Release/7.8.0-News (meanwhile, 7.8.2 has been published).

Comment: Default GRASS GIS in MX 19 is 7.6.0. I don't want my system broken

Comment: Now, I have cleaned install MX 19. Now no Gtk warning. But, still same. Window GRASS quit after I import shapefile.

Comment: Do you use the wxGUI itself or launch v.import on command line? If the former, please try the latter.

Comment: ScreenToClient cannot work when toplevel window is not shown. G__open(read): Unable to open '/home/mega/grass2/PERMANENT/.
tmp/mega/vector/trAreas55950/frmt': No such file or
directory.
That is the message.

Comment: it is same with : https://trac.osgeo.org/grass/ticket/3886

Comment: ok, let's investigate via that ticket....

Comment: Unfortunately. No answer in that ticket yet.